# Правильное написание фразы "сроком на тридцать двое суток"

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Подскажите, как правильно написать "сроком на тридцать двое суток","сроком на тридцать трое суток", "сроком на тридцать четверо суток" и т. д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно только: "Сроком на тридцать два дня".

> Вы знаете, как прочитать сочетание числительного с существительным
>   сутки? Всё ясно, пока перед нами сочетание 20 (двадцать) суток, 21
>   (двадцать одни) сутки. Однако на следующие сутки мы окажемся в трудном
>   положении: нельзя сказать ни «двадцать два сутки», ни «двадцать две
>   сутки», и остаётся, как «жест отчаяния», — «двадцать двое суток», но
>   это не соответствует литературной норме.
>
> Дело в том, что существительные, имеющие форму только множественного
>   числа, сочетаются не с количественными числительными два, три, четыре,
>   а с собирательными двое, трое, четверо. Однако собирательное
>   числительное не может входить в составное числительное, которое должно
>   быть образовано из одних количественных числительных.
>
> В нормативной речи эту грамматическую несочетаемость числительных 22,
>   23, 24 и т.п. с существительными, не имеющими формы единственного
>   числа, мы преодолеваем или заменой таких существительных: поход
>   продолжался 22 дня, или изменением конструкции: поход продолжался в
>   течение двадцати двух суток.
>
> В деловой речи при существительных ножницы, сани, часы, щипцы и т.п. в
>   аналогичных случаях добавляется слово штука: двадцать две штуки
>   ножниц; купили сани в количестве двадцати двух (штук).

https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/88923/35/Rozental%27_-_Govorite_i_pishite_po-russki_pravil%27no.html

Comment: "на тридцать два дня" — может, точнее будет "на тридцать два дня и ночи"? :)

Comment: @grizzly *на тридцать два дня и ночи* - я видел смайлик, но отвечу серьезно. Нет, точнее не будет. "День" в одном их значений - вполне подходящий синим суткам. А вот "день и ночь" таковім не является, разве что в народно-поэтическом стиле...

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в именительном и сходном с ним винительном падеже (как в Ваших словосочетаниях) количественные числительные не согласуются с именами существительными, а **управляют** ими.
При числительных два, три, четыре (а также в составных 22, 23, 24, 32, 33, 34...) **существительные ставятся в родительном падеже единственного числа.** Например, тридцать два стула, двадцать три портрета, сорок четыре книги.

При сочетании составных числительных, оканчивающихся на два, три, четыре, с именами существительными, которые употребляются только во множественном числе (сутки, будни, ножницы, плоскогубцы), формы именительного (и винительного) падежа **следует заменять другим оборотом.**
Нельзя сказать сроком на тридцать два (две, двое) суток.
Рекомендуется: сроком на тридцать два дня.

[Сочетания количественных числительных с именами существительными](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать падежную форму: *на срок, равный (чему?) тридцати двум суткам.*

Менять сутки на дни - это не самый лучший выход, иногда речь идет именно о сутках, а не о днях.

Но выход есть.

Несочетаемость в числовом обороте связана с тем, что числительные, имеющие форму только мн. числа (сутки), образуют счетные обороты с использованием собирательных числительных: двое суток.

Однако собирательные числительные не входят в составные числительные: нельзя сказать *тридцать двое суток.*

Но это невозможно только в И.-В. падеже, а в косвенных падежах "сутки" сочетаются уже с обычными числительными.

Таким образом, используя косвенные падежи, мы решаем эту проблему.

Форма замены: *сроком на двое суток (В.п.) - на срок, равный двум суткам (Д.п.).*